# Writing an SQL statement that references a nested VARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

I am trying to write an SQL statement that queries a column `actors` (defined as `VARRAY(5)`) in a table named `movie` without using PL/SQL, to answer the question:

> List any actors that appear in multiple movies, showing the movie title and actor

```
select a.column_value, count(*), m.title
from movie m, table (m.actors) a
where count(*) > 2,
group by a.column_value;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `movie`, some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link below the question. Do not post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `HAVING` clause for checking the condition instead of where clause and additionally `LISTAGG` may be used to show the movie titles.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE actortype IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(20);
/

create table movie ( id integer , title VARCHAR2(100), actors actortype );

INSERT INTO movie (
     id,
     title,
     actors
) VALUES (
     1,
     'The Shawshank Redemption',
     actortype('Morgan Freeman','Tim Robbins','Bob Gunton')
);
INSERT INTO movie (
     id,
     title,
     actors
) VALUES (
     1,
     'The Dark Knight',
     actortype('Morgan Freeman','Christian Bale','Heath Ledger')
);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT a.column_value as Actor,
       COUNT(*) as num_of_movies,
       LISTAGG( m.title, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY id ) as movies
FROM movie m,
     TABLE ( m.actors ) a
GROUP BY a.column_value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

ACTOR          NUM_OF_MOVIES MOVIES
------------  -------------  -------
Morgan Freeman  2            The Dark Knight,The Shawshank Redemption
```